# How we can create a array propertyin wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I mean to say i am sending array in wso2esb using iterator via wso2dss .In wso2 dss i am using returned generated key.so i am retrieving that value but how can i keep that all array values in single property
i used many ways in wsoesb but i am able to retrive single value which is first object of array

```
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
             name="Name"
             expression="//s:name"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
```

and i am trying to count this value which is i got

```
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
             name="Total"
             expression="count(//s:name)"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
```

in this case i am getting Total=1.0
but in my array i has a 25 elements of objects will u please help me for this...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store array in a property. You may try a class mediator, to read and count the array values.